# Проблемы с подключение статических файлов к HTML с gorilla/mix Go

Tags: html, css, golang

В HTML я подключил css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
```

Вот код в main.go:

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var templates *template.Template

func main() {
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("ui/html/*.html"))

    log.Println("Server will start at http://localhost:8080/")

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", home).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/forum", forum).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/adviсe", adviсe).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui/static/"))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))

}
```

И код в handlers.go:

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home_page.html", r)
}

func forum(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "forum.html", r)
}

func adviсe(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "adviсe.html", r)
}
```

Сервер не видит css

Answer (score 1):

вместо:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui/static/"))
r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

я вставил:

```
s := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui/static/")))
r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(s)
```

И стили работают
Вот моя исправленная функция main:

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("ui/html/*.html"))

    log.Println("Server will start at http://localhost:8080/")

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", home).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/forum", forum).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/adviсe", adviсe).Methods("GET")

    s := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui/static/")))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(s)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
```